# Make String into only 1 line

Tags: string, delphi

I have an output that is basically a paragraph and when I try to search the string for a substring, if that substring is split up it doesnt' work. How can I make the paragraph string into just 1 line?

Example string:

```
I have an output that is basically a paragraph and when I try 
to search the string for a substring, if that substring is split up it 
doesn't work. How can I make the paragraph string into just 1 line?
```

substring: "it doesn't work"

When I try to search for that substring, it doesn't return true.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems like you want to treat newlines as spaces. Writing efficient search algorithms is not trivial, but an approach that *works* and answers the question in your title, is

```
str := StringReplace(str, sLineBreak, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

That is, we simply replace all linebreaks with spaces. Without the magic constants, this is

```
str := StringReplace(str, #13#10, #32, [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Perhaps there are already spaces between the words, in addition to the linebreaks? Then just remove the linebreaks, without adding spaces:

```
str := StringReplace(str, #13#10, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: I wonder why finding a substring wouldn't work. That can only happen if the newline was added inside the substrings to be found. In that case, your solution should work, if it was a newline. But if another type of line break character(s) was used to indicate a soft newline (e.g. for word wrap), it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this function:

```
function NoLineFeed(const s: string): string;
var i: integer;
begin
  result := s;
  for i := 1 to length(result) do
    if ord(result[i])<32 then
      result[i] := ' ';
end;
```

It will change any control character (#10,#13,#9...) into a space, so the text will be on the same line. It will also be faster than calling `StringReplace()`.

*Edit:*

```
function NoLineFeed(const s: string): string;
var i: integer;
begin
  result := s;
  for i := length(result) downto 1 do
    if ord(result[i])<32 then
      if (i>1) and (ord(result[i-1])<=32) then
        delete(result,i,1) else
        result[i] := ' ';
end;
```

So that it will change #13#10 into one single ' '.

Comment: Well, truth be told, it does not even handle the case #13#10, which will be converted to #32#32, and hence there will be no match.

Comment: @Andreas Of course, but it's faster than deleting the duplicates. I've edited to avoid creating two spaces.

Comment: When you delete(result,i,1) one character is skipped.

Comment: @jordani NO character is skipped, since I'm loop in reverse order: from length(result) downto 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
S := 'paragraph here';
S := AdjustLineBreaks(S, tlbsLF);
S := StringReplace(S, #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
I := Pos('search string here', S);
```